# Call bootstrap to show hash link in url, when user clicks on page-scroll(anchor)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and its "page-scroll".

Page-scroll work properly, except when user clicks on menu item, the URL doesn't change.

For example when user clicks on menu item "PRODUCTS", I want that URL changes from http://dev01-www.erisata.lt/en to http://dev01-www.erisata.lt/en#products

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Yes, that's expected ... its the default behaviour of bootstrap scroll. You need to override the default behaviour with JQuery of your own.

Comment: Yes, I know, I tried a lot of different codes, but it's not working and I'm new user to JQuery... So I'm wondering maybe someone knows the exact code for this solution. Anyway, thanks for your response!

Comment: I have already posted it. try it & let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's expected ... its the default behaviour of bootstrap scroll. You need to override the default behaviour with JQuery of your own.

Try the below JQuery code, I have already tested it on your website & works well.

In your `scrolling-nav.js` your `.bind()` should look like below

```
//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        window.location.hash = this.hash; //add only this line here
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Yes, it's working. But know scrolling animation is effected, its turned off. I need it to be working. Thanks

Comment: You mean, scroll is not getting animated (no more smooth scroll) ?

Comment: did you remove your previous `$('a.page-scroll').bind('click',` code from your `scrolling-nav.js` ?

Comment: Yes, now I'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token on scrolling.nav.js:12

Comment: That's why, don't remove your previous code, just add to it. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah I checked your website. Cheers!